# Cannot update or create environment in Colab using Conda

Tags: conda, google-colaboratory, virtual-environment

I am trying to install a Conda environment for my thesis in Colab using a *.yml file.

First, I am mounting my drive, copying required files

> ```
> !pip install -q condacolab
> import condacolab
> condacolab.install_anaconda()
> ```

> ```
> %%bash
> mkdir Tez
> cd "/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Tez/RNN_Peng_Xu/"
> cp -r multigraph_transformer /content/Tez
> %cd Tez/multigraph_transformer/
> ```

Then, running below blocks got me stuck since it cannot create or update conda environment using this block of code: (I have checked I am in the right directory with *.yml file)

> ```
> !conda update -n base -f MGT_environment.yml
> ```

*Error message:*

```
WARNING: The --force flag will be removed in a future conda release.
         See 'conda update --help' for details about the --force-reinstall
         and --clobber flags.



PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix.
  prefix: /usr/local
  package name: mgt_environment.yml
```

I am giving the *.yml files first rows here. Can you help me where is my error? Appreciated in advance.

---

```
name: env182
channels:
  - pytorch
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - _anaconda_depends=2019.03=py37_0
  - _ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf=0.1.0=py37_0
  - _libgcc_mutex=0.1=main
  - _tflow_select=2.1.0=gpu
  - absl-py=0.7.1=py37_0
  - alabaster=0.7.12=py37_0
  - anaconda=2019.07=py37_0
-...... and more....
```

Comment: Looks like typo: `conda env update` not `conda update` for YAMLs.

Comment: Voting to close as typo unless there is more info.